# Apps Script - creating google form but get respond in same database (spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

**Overall idea**:

Creating a form2 according to form1 that submitted by 1st user for higher level approval by sending form2 through email

*Amended*
**problem**:

I need to create form2 where all data vary according to what form1 responses, overall arrangement of form item question will be same, but content would be different. By chance if anyone know, I can amend a form (let's call v1) to person1, and amend the same form (v2) to person2, where I'm using same form ID for the purpose of approval workflow, in anywhere the details in v1 wont be updated as according to details in v2 (as generally google form will update all item question changes and republish automatically), maybe add UID to each form?

**method tried**: creating new form, too much spreadsheet that link to different form

**method2 tried**: using same form, changing the content inside, but error happen when amending form2 more than 1 time. when send out two form, the version1 of form2 would be live update to version2 of form2

Please help. if you have any other suggestion, please feedback.

Codes added later time:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ANufFqk/edit#gid=681916147");
  var formsDB = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hGe1oStPoft9kfUNFA/edit#gid=138650439");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('ManagerRequest');
  var AllRange = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(), 12).getValues();
  var LastRequest = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getRange("B1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(), 12).getValues();
  ws.getRange(1, 9).setValue("Operation Lead Approval"); 
  ws.getRange(1, 10).setValue("NOC Approval"); 

  var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues();

// to find last request proceed
  LastTicket = LastRequest.length;
  while(LastTicket > 0 && data[LastTicket][1] == "") {
    LastTicket--;
    if (data[LastTicket][1] == "Request Number"){ NewTicket = 0}
    else {NewTicket = data[LastTicket][1]}
  }
  Logger.log("LastRequestNo " + LastTicket + " and NewRequestNo " + (+NewTicket + 1));


  for (var i = (+LastTicket); i < AllRange.length - 1; i++) {
   NewTicket += 1
   ws.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(NewTicket);
   var session = AllRange[i];
   var TicketNo = NewTicket;
   var ManagerName = session[2];
   var Country = session[4];
   var RequestReason = session[5];
   var ManRequest = session[6];
   var OperationLead = session[7];
   Logger.log("Request Number " + NewTicket + "; " + ManagerName + " is requesting " + ManRequest + " manpower for country " + Country + " because " + RequestReason );



    var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xeNFpSxxmQUqfDdFo504/edit')

    var formid = form.getId();
    Logger.log(formid);

    form.getTitle('Request ticket:-').setHelpText(NewTicket);
    form.getTitle('Detail for recruitment:-').setHelpText("Requester: " + ManagerName + "\nManpower Requesting: " + ManRequest + "\nCountry: " + Country + "\nReason: " + RequestReason);


    var publishURL = form.getPublishedUrl();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(OperationLead, 'Manpower request from ' + Country , "Hi "+Country +" Operation Lead,\n\n\nPlease review the google form link below and make decision upon the request.\n "+publishURL+"\n\nThanks and Regards,\nHuman Resource Auto Sender");
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm()).onFormSubmit().create();


  }

}


  function onFormSubmit(e){
    //var forms = FormApp.openById(e);
    var forms = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var formResponses = forms.response();

    for (var i=0; i < formResponses.length; i++){
      var formResponse = formResponses[i];
      var itemReponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
      for ( var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j ++){
        itemReponse = itemReponses[j];
        Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
        (i + 1).toString(),
        itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
        itemResponse.getResponse());

      }
     }
    var formsDB = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hGe1oPoft9kfUNFA/edit#gid=138650439");
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ebobAddzEP3i_ANufFqk/edit#gid=681916147");
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName('ManagerRequest');
    var AllRange = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(), 12).getValues();

    for (var j=1; j< AllRange.length; j++){
      if (ws.getRange(j, 2).getValue() == ResponsesTicket)
      {ws.getRange(j, 9).setValue(OlApproval);
      ws.getRange(j, 10).setValue(Comment);}

    }
  }
```

Comment: Using Sheets as a database is not a good idea, as it slows-down with each new row. You could also face [quota limits issues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations). Could you post the code you tried? I couldn't understand what's the objective.

Comment: @Jescanellas, hi please find the code above, but the google link is not available for open. please help. thank you. Basically i want to generate google form2 according to form1 submitted, and info from form1 should be amended in form2, so that the higher level people can approve by referring to the request from form1

Comment: @DamonLim I'm probably tell you something you already know but... the term for this is "approval workflow". It's not something that is natively built-in to Google Forms. I suppose it can be done because there are many add-ons that provide this service, but I doubt it would be worth building from scratch.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, maybe i change abit my tough side, in anywhere i can amend a form (let's call v1) to person1, and amend the same form (v2) to person2, where i'm using same form ID for the purpose of approval workflow, in anywhere the details in v1 wont be amended to v2

Comment: Are you using the free Google service, or the "paid" service?

Comment: OK. Let's explore: 1) you need a unique identifier for Form#1 response. 2) Assume you generate Form#2 and add a question "Approve/Disapprove" how does Person#2 know that there is a form that they need to submit. Maybe an alternative is to send an email to person#2 (containing the fields from form#1; unique identifier is in Subject). Maybe??  email contains two hyperlinks "Approve" and "Disapprove" - they create a reply to specific-purpose email accounts; setup a script in Google Sheets to get threads from each email account, and that way you can update the record of whether FORM#1 was approved

Comment: I've just realised that you've changed your question. You might get a better response if you keep to the same question here, and start a "new" question for a different topic.

Comment: @Tedinoz hi, i'm using free version. i dont change question, just make it more clear to what exactly my problem is

Comment: @Tedinoz, sorry for late replying, good idea but how can i get the hyperlink for "approve", "reject" work?

Comment: @DamonLim May I make a suggestion? Write down what you are trying to do and why, what you have done so far, what research you have done, what code you are using. Have someone else proof read it and make sure that it is clear with no assumptions, no misunderstandings, etc. Then delete this question, and submit a new question. "but how can i get the hyperlink for "approve", "reject" work?" - same as above.

Comment: @Tedinoz Hi, done creating new post. please helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247024/how-can-i-get-the-hyperlink-for-approve-reject-work-in-email-using-apps-scr