# How can i get the hyperlink for "Approve", "Reject" work in Email using Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Problem: Seeking approval from manager upon each google form submission, the manager need to review the details and clicking approve or reject

BUT: how can i get the hyperlink for "approve", "reject" work

Desired solution: preferable Google Apps Scripts, when respondent click approve or submit, should save the response into google sheet and send second email to second layer approval

Tried: Able to extract detail from google form, but not able to perform approval and rejection button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call the function in server side script : Google App Script when I hit a hyperlink in Gmail body (client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950204/how-do-i-call-the-function-in-server-side-script-google-app-script-when-i-hit)

Answer (score 1):

A possible workflow is as following:

- Use the [form submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) - either for FormApp or, optionally,  for SpreadsheetApp - if the responses are automatically stored in a destination sheet
- Trigger onFormSubmit a notification email to be sent to the manager
- Implement into the the notification email two links - one for approval, one for rejection
- Create two [WebApps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) - one that contains a script approving the form submission, copying the form response into a google sheet and sending emails to a second level approval; the second Web App contains a script that should be run in case of rejection (e.g. a notification email to the submitter about the rejection)
- Use the Web App URLs as approval and rejection links in the notification mails to the manager

I hope those instructions are clear enough and helpful to you!